# Tomcat: How to stop Tomcat creating a session for all requests?

Tags: tomcat, haproxy

HAProxy is pinging tomcat and requesting a very small page causing Tomcat to create a new session every 2 seconds. Is there is a way to programmatically (or through a config) tell Tomcat to not create a new session for a specific page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You don't need to implement anything, it's already there ;)!**

Tomcat container provides **Crawler Session Manager Valve** (valve is just like HttpServletFilter, but inside Tomcat container (lower level).
You can find more details here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Crawler_Session_Manager_Valve

You just add **<Valve>** tag to your tomcat's **server.xml** with proper configuration. Remember to provide regular expressions for bot user agents.

For example

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CrawlerSessionManagerValve"
crawlerUserAgents=".*googlebot.\*|.*yahoo.*" sessionInactiveInterval="600"/>
```

You can look at the source code of valve: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.11/org/apache/catalina/valves/CrawlerSessionManagerValve.java

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. It's a bit complicated, but works well for us.

Basically, we change the Filter chain for sessions. We do this for bots (Google, Pear, Yahoo).

Create a new Filter and register it, then use this source for the Filter class:

```
public class BotFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
  private int inactive_seconds = 5*60;
  private String[] bots = new String[] { "googlebot", //google
    "msnbot", //msn
    "slurp", //yahoo
    "libcurl", //curl, sometimes used with bigbrother
    "bigbrother", //bigbrother availability check
    "whatsup", //whatsup availability check
    "surveybot", //unknown
    "wget", // nocomment
    "speedyspider", //http://www.entireweb.com/about/search_tech/speedyspider/
    "nagios-plugins", //Alle Nagios-Abfragen
    "pear.php.net", //Irgendwelcher PHP-Scheiß
    "mj12bot", //http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/dsearch/mj12bot.php
    "bingbot", //M$ Bing
    "dotbot", //We are just a few Seattle based guys trying to figure out how to make internet data as open as possible.
    "aggregator:spinn3r", //http://spinn3r.com/robot
    "baiduspider" //http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm
  };
  private HashMap<String, HttpSession> botsessions;

  public BotFilter() {
    this.botsessions = new HashMap<String, HttpSession>();
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

  }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
      HttpServletRequest httprequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
      try {
        String useragent = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("User-Agent");
        if (useragent == null) {
          ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
        }
        useragent = useragent.toLowerCase();
        if (httprequest.getSession(false) == null) {
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.bots.length; i++) {
          if (useragent.indexOf(this.bots[i]) > -1) {
            String key = httprequest.getRemoteAddr() + useragent;
            boolean SessionIsInvalid=false;
            synchronized(this.botsessions) {
              try {
                if(this.botsessions.get(key)!=null)
                  this.botsessions.get(key).getAttributeNames();
              } catch (java.lang.IllegalStateException ise) {
                SessionIsInvalid = true;
              }
              if(this.botsessions.get(key)==null||SessionIsInvalid) {
                httprequest.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(this.inactive_seconds);
                if(SessionIsInvalid)
                  this.botsessions.remove(key); //Remove first, if in there
                this.botsessions.put(key, httprequest.getSession()); //Then add a little spice
              } else {
                next.doFilter(new BotFucker(httprequest, this.botsessions.get(key)), response);
                return;
              }
            }
          };
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        //Error handling code
      }
    }
    next.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  public void destroy() {

  }
}
```

And this little one for the redirection class:

```
public class BotFucker extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

  HttpSession session;

  public BotFucker(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    super(request);
    this.session = session;
  }
  @Override
  public HttpSession getSession(boolean create) {
    return this.session;
  }
  @Override
  public HttpSession getSession() {
    return this.session;
  }
}
```

These two classes re-use the sessions that the bots had before, if they connect again using the same IP within a given time limit. We're not 100% sure what this does to the data that the bot receives, but as this code is running for many months now and solved our problem (multiple connects/sessions per second per IP from Google).

And before somebody tries to help: The problem has been submitted multiple times to Google via Webmaster interface. The crawling interval has been lowered to the lowest possible setting, and the problem spawned a 3x reply thread on the appropriate forum without any hint as to why this problem exists.

Answer (score 3):

Don't point it at your application pages.  If httpchk is pulling a JSP page, it will create a session.

Can you point HAProxy at a static HTML page for your httpchk?

Aiternatively, create a servlet that checks whatever health you need to validate but doesn't create a session.  (à la `HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)`)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `session=false` directive in the JSP.

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
```

Comment: would have been nice to know back then....I typically use playframework instead as the footprint is only around 20MB or less compared to tomcat's 200M or so and it flies...much much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Is this page part of a regular web app or a standalone web app?

If the page is part of a standalone web app i.e. only that page exists in that app, you could set a low session timeout in the web.xml for that app. Liek 2 minutes or even lower.

Otherwise, there is no solution to your problem on the Tomcat end. Tomcat will create a new session if an earlier session id is not sent along with the request.